# How to solve error on Laravel Project running?

Tags: laravel

I am getting the below error when I run php artisan serve

```
<header id="page-topbar">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <div class="d-flex">
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                <!-- item-->
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="mdi mdi-account-circle font-size-17 align-middle mr-1"></i> @lang('translation.profile')</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-danger" href="javascript:void();" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                    <i class="bx bx-power-off font-size-17 align-middle mr-1 text-danger"></i>
                    @lang('translation.logout')
                </a>
                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    @csrf
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Tue Feb  9 14:23:03 2021] PHP 7.4.3 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
```

I can also see some code on the rendered HTML page, shown in the image below :
[image]

If i use **{{asset('img/pub.png)}}**, then it shows as same in inspect element.

Please help me resolve this. Thanks

Comment: There's a missing single quote in **{{asset('img/pub.png)}}**

Answer (score 0):

What is the `</button>` doing there on the 4th line? Can you try removing it and see if it works?

Also, I could see 5 closing divs `</div>` but only 4 open divs `<div>`. Can you check your code again?

Comment: its just code for dummy example but this type of code shows when i hit php artisan serve